# Angularjs uigrid filter button showing as chinese font

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, grid, angular-ui-grid

I have used angularjs ui-grid in my project.
Below is my code

```html
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js-image-slider.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/js-image-slider.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui-grid.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/gemscustomstyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js-image-slider.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AngularGrid/angularjs.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AngularGrid/angular-ng-route.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AngularGrid/ui-grid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller="CitywiseReportController">
    
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridoptions" ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-resize-columns class="myGrid" style="width: 98%"></div>
    </div>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.grid']);

    app.controller('CitywiseReportController', function ($scope, CitywiseReportService) {
      
        $scope.configureHeadCountGrid = function () {
            $scope.gridoptions = {
            data:'cityReportData',
                enableGridMenu: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableColumnResizing: true
            }
            //The grid options
            $scope.gridoptions.columnDefs = [
                            { name: 'Duty Travel ID', field: 'DutyTravelId', width: '90' },
                            { name: 'Staff ID', field: 'StaffNumber', width: '90' },
                            { name: 'Staff Name', field:'StaffName', width: '120' },
                            { name: 'DT Cost Center', field: 'CostCenter', width: '120' },
                            { name: 'DT Travel Category', field: 'TravelCategory', width: '120' },
                            { name: 'City Code', field: 'CityCode', width: '60' },
                            { name: 'City Name', field: 'CityName', width: '100' },
                            { name: 'Departure Date', field: 'DepartureDate', width: '120', type: 'date', format: '{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}' },
                            { name: 'Arrival Date', field: 'ArrivalDate', width: '120', type: 'date', format: '{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}' }
                        ];

        }
        getStudents();
        function getStudents() {
            CitywiseReportService.getStudents()
            .success(function (studs) {
                $scope.cityReportData = studs;
               
            })
            .error(function (error) {
              
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
               
            });
        }
        $scope.configureHeadCountGrid();
    });

    app.factory('CitywiseReportService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var CitywiseReportService = {};
        CitywiseReportService.getStudents = function () {
           
            return $http.get('/DutyTravel/GetCityWiseDTReport');
        };
        return CitywiseReportService;

    } ]);
</script>
```

but when grid displays grid filter icon image showing as chinese font.

[image: See this image]

and in chrome console it is showing 
http://localhost:58206/Content/ui-grid.woff 
http://localhost:58206/Content/ui-grid.ttf

Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `mimeType` settings inside your `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your quick response i added this in my application web.config and checked it was not working the same again i added for view web.config under webserver tag but did not get any luck. got the same error in console. can you tell me how it is finding the image icon for filtering?

Comment: Sorry pankaj actually i did not added those two woff and ttf file in my folder i got that file and added and now it's work like charm. thanks